# Comparing PPI weights for USA and GER

Tags: price-index

I am trying to explain why the size of producer price changes for Germany is significantly smaller than for the USA. For this purpose I wanted to look into the calculation method for both Producer Price Indices (PPI) and see if they weights for the industries differ. Different weights cold influence the size, i.e. if an industry with large changes is weighted stronger in the US PPI.

However, I have problems finding the the weights for the US PPI, as the bureau of labor statistics doesn't officially publish them. therefore I have two questions:

1. Does anyone know / have a source for the US PPI weights by NAICS industry classes?
2. What alternative explanations exist for the differences in PPI change sizes?

Comment: https://www.bls.gov/ppi/#tables seems to point to "relative importance"

Comment: @Henry yes, and I have looked into them. However, they are only given for the internal "commodity type" classification, not for NAICS.